# Using guards and sectioning

Tags: haskell

I'm beginner at Haskell, for my homework I have to write fuctions in 2 versions: with and without using sectioning. One of this function should return True if argument is greater than 100, and False otherwise.

The function without sectioning works well:

```
f5 x | x>100 = True
     | otherwise = False
```

But the second version does not:

```
f5' | (>100) = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Can you tell me how to write this function properly?

Comment: Related question: how would you simplify `if x > 100 then True else False` to not use redundant branching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function without sectioning is too complicated, and is causing you trouble. It should be

```
f5 x = x > 100
```

Because

```
(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

already produces a `Bool`. There is no need to use guards on top. Think about it: if `x > 100` is `True`, then you take the first branch of your guard and return `True`, and if it's `False` you take the second branch and return `False`. You can just eliminate the extra branching without losing anything.

Then you just need to punch out the `x`:

```
f5 = (> 100)
```

---

Your original fails because

```
(> 100) :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool
```

is a function that eventually gives a `Bool`, not a `Bool` itself. Thus, it explodes when you try to use it in a guard, where an ordinary `Bool` is expected.

Comment: You may want to add why the OP's code failed (using a function in a guard).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is the right way. But for the sake of argument, there is another way to pointfree a guard: using view patterns.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

-- Don't ever do this :)
f5 ((> 100) -> True) =  True
f5 _                 = False
```

It has the effect that you're looking for, "abstracting" the variable out of the guard. It's just that we turned the guard into a pattern to do so.

Comment: For the sake of argument?  I disagree!